# Need help to bootstrap modal asp.net

Tags: jquery, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I have an if statement in the code behind for an asp.net page, like this:

```
If Session("UserActiv") IsNot Nothing Then
    If Session("UserActiv").ToString() = "N" Then
        ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(),
            "Details", "LoadDetails();", True)
    End If
Else
    ClientScript.RegisterStartupScript(Me.GetType(),
        "Details", "LoadDetails();", True)
End If
```

If my session is not nothing, and if its N then it run the function LoadDetails()
If nothing then it also load the function, and if Y then do nothing.

Then I have the function on my main page, my only problem is, that it load the function every time I load the page, also if the session is Y, i have checked for upper Y/N and lower y/n issues and all is in UPPER case. so no problem there.

My loadDetails() function is like this:

```
<script language="javascript" type="text/javascript">
    function LoadDetails() {
        myModal.load();
    }

    $(document).ready(function () {

        $("#myModal").modal({
            "backdrop": "static",
            // if true, then the backdrop can be closed with a click
            // if false then there is no backdrop.
            "keyboard": false
        })

});
</script>
```

I'd like this to load at page_load like now, BUT only if the session is nothing or if its N. How would I go about this?

EDIT................EDIT................EDIT................EDIT................EDIT................EDIT................EDIT................
@RYAN

if i do it like this, nothing happens when the session is N

```
Imports System.Web.Security
Imports System.IO
Imports System.Data
Imports System.Data.OleDb

Partial Class _default
Inherits System.Web.UI.Page

Protected Sub Page_Load(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles Me.Load

    If Session("UserActiv") IsNot Nothing Then
        If Session("UserActiv").ToString() = "N" Then
            runJQueryCode("$('#myModal').modal('show');")
        End If
    Else
        runJQueryCode("$('#myModal').modal('show');")
    End If

    If (Not Page.IsPostBack) Then

        Dim htmlString As New StringBuilder()
        ' Has the request been authenticated?
        If Request.IsAuthenticated Then
            ' Display generic identity information.
            ' This is always available, regardless of the type of
            ' authentication.
            htmlString.Append("<h3>Generic User Information</h3>")
            htmlString.Append("<b>name: </b>")
            htmlString.Append(User.Identity.Name)
            htmlString.Append("<br><b>Authenticated With: </b>")
            htmlString.Append(User.Identity.AuthenticationType)
            htmlString.Append("<br><b>User ID: </b>")
            htmlString.Append(Session("UserID"))
            htmlString.Append("<br><br>")
            htmlString.Append(Session("UserActiv"))
        End If
        ' Was forms authentication used?

        If TypeOf User.Identity Is FormsIdentity Then
            ' Get the ticket.
            Dim ticket As FormsAuthenticationTicket = (DirectCast(User.Identity, FormsIdentity)).Ticket
            htmlString.Append("<h3>Ticket User Information</h3>")
            htmlString.Append("<b>Name: </b>")
            htmlString.Append(ticket.Name)
            htmlString.Append("<br><b>Issued at: </b>")
            htmlString.Append(ticket.IssueDate)
            htmlString.Append("<br><b>Expires at: </b>")
            htmlString.Append(ticket.Expiration)
            htmlString.Append("<br><b>Cookie version: </b>")
            htmlString.Append(ticket.Version)
            htmlString.Append("<br><b>Cookie CookiePath: </b>")
            htmlString.Append(ticket.CookiePath)
            htmlString.Append("<br><b>Cookie Expired: </b>")
            htmlString.Append(ticket.Expired)
            htmlString.Append("<br><b>Cookie isPersistent: </b>")
            htmlString.Append(ticket.IsPersistent)
            htmlString.Append("<br><b>User Data: </b>")
            htmlString.Append(ticket.UserData)

            ' Display the information.
            LegendInfo.Text = htmlString.ToString()
        End If

        If User.IsInRole("Manager") Then
            ' Display sensitive material
            Session("userrole") = "Site Manager"
        ElseIf User.IsInRole("Admin") Then
            ' Display sensitive material
            Session("userrole") = "Site Admin"
        ElseIf User.IsInRole("User") Then
            ' Display sensitive material
            Session("userrole") = "Alm. Bruger"
        Else
            ' Display only bland material
        End If
    End If
End Sub

Public Function runJQueryCode(ByVal message As String) As Boolean
    Dim requestSM As ScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page)
    If requestSM IsNot Nothing AndAlso requestSM.IsInAsyncPostBack Then
        ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), getjQueryCode(message), True)
    Else
        Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), getjQueryCode(message), True)
    End If

    Return True
End Function

Private Function getjQueryCode(ByVal jsCodetoRun As String) As String
    Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
    sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function() {")
    sb.AppendLine(jsCodetoRun)
    sb.AppendLine(" });")

    Return sb.ToString()
End Function

'Private Sub cmdSignOut_ServerClick(ByVal sender As Object, ByVal e As System.EventArgs) Handles cmdSignOut.ServerClick
'FormsAuthentication.SignOut()
'FormsAuthentication.RedirectToLoginPage()
'End Sub
End Class
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the following sections of code to your VB.net code:

```
Public Function runJQueryCode(ByVal message As String) As Boolean
        Dim requestSM As ScriptManager = ScriptManager.GetCurrent(Page)
        If requestSM IsNot Nothing AndAlso requestSM.IsInAsyncPostBack Then
            ScriptManager.RegisterClientScriptBlock(Page, GetType(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), getjQueryCode(message), True)
        Else
            Page.ClientScript.RegisterClientScriptBlock(GetType(Page), Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), getjQueryCode(message), True)
        End If

        Return True
    End Function

    Private Function getjQueryCode(ByVal jsCodetoRun As String) As String
        Dim sb As New StringBuilder()
        sb.AppendLine("$(document).ready(function() {")
        sb.AppendLine(jsCodetoRun)
        sb.AppendLine(" });")

        Return sb.ToString()
    End Function
```

Then use:

```
If Session("UserActiv") IsNot Nothing Then
        If Session("UserActiv").ToString() = "N" Then
           runJQueryCode("SUCCESS!modaljquerystuff")
        End If
    Else
        runJQueryCode("FAIL!modaljquerystuff")
End If
```

Comment: Hi Ryan im new to this, where do i call the myModal div in this ex !?

Comment: In this example:

runJQueryCode("$('#myModal').modal('show');")

Comment: What does your ASP code look like? You may need to add an <asp:ScriptManager runat="server" id="lulz"></asp:ScriptManager> to your ASP page to run the JS.

Comment: i thx. now its working, i just have one question, how du i add static backdrop to, runJQueryCode("$('#myModal').modal('show');")

Comment: i have tryed this code, but with no luck, runJQueryCode("$('#myModal').modal(show: 'true', backdrop: 'static', keyboard: 'false');")

Comment: i think i got it with runJQueryCode("$('#myModal').modal({show:true, backdrop:'static', keyboard:false});")